# Using CheckBox in Django FilterSet

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to find any solutions to this issue..

In my `models.py` I have a class called `Course` like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    seats_occupied = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    seats_available = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=25)
    # etc...
```

In my `filters.py` I have this filter for it:

```
class CourseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    seats_occupied = BooleanFilter(field_name='seats_occupied', method='filter_not_full_courses')


    def filter_not_full_courses(self, queryset, name, value):
        # construct the full lookup expression.
        Course.objects.filter(~Q(seats_occupied=25)) 
        lookup = '__'.join([name, 'lt'])
        return queryset.filter(**{lookup: F('seats_available')})
```

At this point, I need to enter a number to see if `seats_occupied` is less than that number. But I would like to just have a CheckBox or Possibly a multiple choice with "open/full" courses, that will only give me the courses that are not full. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create BooleanFilter this way, this way you filter all courses where seats_occupied < seats_available

```
from django.db.models import F
from django import forms

class CourseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    seats_occupied = django_filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='seats_occupied', method='filter_not_full_courses', widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
    def filter_not_full_courses(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value:
            lookup = '__'.join([name, 'lt'])
            queryset = queryset.exclude(seats_occupied=F('seats_available')).filter(**{lookup: F('seats_available')})
        return queryset
```

Comment: Okay, so if the lookup expression is:  `Course.objects.filter(~Q(seats_occupied=25))`. How do I return that? Cause when I try to plug this in I'm getting `filter_not_full_courses() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Comment: Looks like you need to add 'self', please try to plug the edited version.

Comment: You can also filter this way: ```Course.objects.filter(~Q(seats_occupied__lt=F('seats_available'))```

Comment: So I edited my question so you can see what it looks like now. However, it still gives me all courses no matter if i do Yes or No, and ive made sure the class is full when I test this. How do I get different query results based on yes or no?

Comment: This filter should show you all courses in which seats_occupied < seats_available. Please try another edited version of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so this works. But it gives the same result if I do Yes or No, and when I do Unknown it displays all courses. Ideally, it would show only open course (not full) when Yes, and all courses when No

Comment: @LukaJozić Please see my final solution, I've added ```widget=forms.CheckboxInput``` , and also filter only ```if value```, I've tested it, it works. Please add upvote if it works for you.